# Push-button light switch on/off reversed

Tags: lamp

I bought an office lamp with a power button that you push to activate, where having the light on means the button is further out (up) than off, and having the light off means the button is further in (down). This is the opposite of what I'm used to, so I'd like to know how to swap the behavior. There's no actual problem, it just looks/feels awkward. Maybe there's no standard or the way these are done nowadays is just random, but it'd be nice to adjust it.

I've tried reversing the plug to no avail. I could try and take it apart but I'm not great with electrical fiddling nor do I even know how feasible/worthwhile it would be to fiddle with this thing (I probably paid $15-30 for it anyway, and I like it, I want to keep it).

The make and model is Room Essentials AL52093.

Comment: I think the only way to fix it would be replacing the switch.  It is the way the switch is made.  Good chance the switch is made to be replaceable and they are just a tiny bit harder to replace than a light bulb.

Comment: I'm not sure what you did to "reverse the plug", but that's _never_ the correct option. You do _NOT_ want to reverse the polarity on a plug (assuming that's what you did) because a switch (in the US, at least) should always break the _HOT_ side of the circuit, not the neutral side. If you're switching the neutral, the light will be off, but there will still be power coming into the socket and you're in for a shock when you go to change a light bulb.

Comment: Also, "out is on" is a fairly common push-button setup, so that doesn't sound all that odd to me.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible push-to-toggle electrical styles for a switch like that. You'll have to open up the lamp and have a look at the switch.

If the switch has just two terminals then it is what it is; the only way to change the switch behavior would be to change the switch.

On the other hand, if the switch has three or more terminals but only two are used, it's likely that the wiring can be re-arranged so that the switch works in the way you desire. You could use an ohm meter to find out which terminals are connected together when the switch is depressed and move the wiring to those terminals.

As an alternative to re-wiring or replacing the switch, you may be able to add an inline switch and use it as your primary control. One style goes at the plug; another style can be installed anywhere along the length of the power cord. (photos: homedepot.com and lowes.com)

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]